# How to append text in page url using wp_link_pages() in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with custom single post layout. The content with this layout comes with appending

> /?L=2

in post url. But now i am facing with a problem that i can't paginate post using wp_link_pages() for next page. How can i add or append

> /?L=2

in pagelink. Like pagelink will be

> http://localhost/wordpress/african-immigrant-climbs-4-floors-with-his-bare-hands-to-save-a-4-year-old-boy/2/?L=2

Next page

> http://localhost/wordpress/african-immigrant-climbs-4-floors-with-his-bare-hands-to-save-a-4-year-old-boy/3/?L=2

By this way. Any better idea for implementing this? the default structure of wp_link_pages is

```
<?php 

wp_link_pages(array(
    'before' => '<div class="next_post"',
    'after' => '</div>',
    'previouspagelink' => '', 
    'nextpagelink' => 'Next Page',
    'pagelink' => '%', 
    'next_or_number' => 'next'
)); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easy, you have to use the `wp_link_pages_link` filter hook, like this

```
function theme_prefix_change_pagination_link($link){
    return str_replace('"><span class="page-number">','?L=2"><span class="page-number">',$link);
}
add_filter('wp_link_pages_link','theme_prefix_change_pagination_link');
```

and in single.php you use wp_link_pages like this

```
wp_link_pages( array(
    'before'      => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'textdomain' ),
    'after'       => '</div>',
    'link_before' => '<span class="page-number">',
    'link_after'  => '</span>',
) );
```